# $l^2$ norm and unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

In the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00519.pdf, in lemma e.5, they state that if $Z\in \mathbb{R}^p$, $||\cdot||$ is the $p$-dimensional $l^2$ norm, and $\mathbb{S}^{p-1}$ is the unit sphere, then
\begin{align}
\Vert Z\Vert=\sup_{u\in \mathbb{S}^{p-1}}u^T z
\end{align}

I don't understand why this holds.

Comment: In this case, the supremum is the same as the maximum. From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $u^Tz\leq\lVert u\rVert\lVert z\rVert=1\lVert z\rVert$, which means that $\lVert z\rVert$ is an upper bound for the product. It's reached when $u=\frac{z}{\lVert z\rVert}$ (since $z^Tz=\lVert z\rVert^2$), so it is the least upper bound. This question is probably a duplicate, so I won't bother posting an answer.

Comment: This basically boils down to the geometrical the interpretation of the dot product, which is the following:

The dot product of the vector $a$ with $u$ is exactly the lenght of $a$ when projected to $u$, which in turn is exactly $$a \cdot u = ||a|| \cos(\theta),$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. 
(I initialy wrote this as an answer, but mr_e_man is right, is probably a duplicate so I delited it).